# jQuery Div Positioning issue

Tags: jquery, position

This has been driving me crazy. I'm trying to position a div near where a search field exists. When the value is entered, the div should move by the cursor, and display the results.

I have a hidden div, outside of all other divs.

```
<div id="search_collection_enc"></div>
```

I retrieve the data, and collect the x/y coordinates of the mouse. These have been put into hidden fields, and I have verified that they exist. I then do the following:

```
current_x_val = $("#current_x").val();
current_y_val = $("#current_y").val();                        
$('#search_collection_enc').css({"position":"absolute","left":current_x_val,"top":current_y_val,"z-index":100});
$("#search_collection_enc").html(coll_rows_html);
$("#search_collection_enc").show();
```

The data gets populated nicely. But the display is always right up in the top left corner.

Any ideas? Driving me around the bend.

Comment: Can you provide an example showing what you are expecting and probably a fiddle with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use units when setting the `top` and `left` properties.

**Edit:** jQuery will coerce integer values to use 'px', but since you are retrieving the values using the `val()` method, `current_x_val` and `current_y_val` are returned as strings and thus won't be coerced.

```
$('#search_collection_enc').css({
    "position":"absolute",
    "left":current_x_val + 'px', //add units to left
    "top":current_y_val + 'px', //add units to top
    "z-index":100
});
```

Comment: Not really, jQuery coerces unit-less numbers to `px`. Though, I'm not sure whether it coerces strings (which is the return of `.val()`) so it may be worth a shot.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much. Will mark you as my answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't coerce strings http://jsfiddle.net/2DFLx/ so an alternative solution is converting the string to number `left: +current_x_val, top: +current_y_val` would also work, but I guess adding `px` is a bit more clear in that aspect.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Good point; I bet you are right about the values being string; I'll update the answer